# Would it possible to use all memory of GPUs with one model?

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch

There is a `model` and two GPUs. I put the `model` on GPU with `model.cuda()`. If I passed a big image to the `model`, it allocated all memory of GPU0 and then it raised `CUDA out of memory` error without allocating any memory of GPU1.

Because there is only one image every `forward()`, I can not use such `torch.nn.DataParallel` things to split input.

Is there any way to use all the memory of GPUs when passing a image to the `model`?

I'm using Python3.7 and Pytorch1.1.

Comment: Not sure what exactly your requirement here is. But take a look at [this excellent article](https://medium.com/huggingface/training-larger-batches-practical-tips-on-1-gpu-multi-gpu-distributed-setups-ec88c3e51255) which discusses in detail about data  parallelism in PyTorch and accommodating larger sized batches when there is no enough memory.

Comment: @scarecrow My batch size is 1. I can't use data parallel, because it requires batch size to be 2 or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can split your model into two submodule. 
like this:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, split_gpus):
        self.large_submodule1 = ...
        self.large_submodule2 = ...

        self.split_gpus = split_gpus
        if split_gpus:
            self.large_submodule1.cuda(0)
            self.large_submodule1.cuda(1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.large_submodule1(x)
        if split_gpus:
            x = x.cuda(1) # P2P GPU transfer
        return self.large_submodule2(x)
```

from the [pytorch discuss](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/split-single-model-in-multiple-gpus/13239/2?u=alpha)